# (lazy) loading google maps is not working after refactoring

Tags: javascript, google-maps, lazy-loading

I only load Google maps When needed. Before I refactored my code, it worked and looked like this:

```
function initialize_map_brand() {
  (...)
}

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    load_google_map('initialize_map_brand');
});
```

After refactoring, my code looks like this:

```
lib = {
    loadGoogleMapScript: function(_callback) {
      (...)
      script.src = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=' +_callback;
    }
}


Page = {
    viewPage: {
        init: function() {
            lib.loadGoogleMapScript(self.initialize_map);
        },
        initialize_map: function() {
            var locations = [ (...)
        }
    }
}

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    Page.viewBPage.init();
});
```

And now I'm getting this error:

> "NetworkError: 400 Bad Request -
>   http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=function%20()%20{var%20locations%20=%20[[%....

It seems it takes the entire function code and passes it in the url. So how can I load the Google Maps script correctly with my new code?

[Se my fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/h20ck6dd/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple-async) You need to provide a string for the url `callback` parameter with the name of a function in the global scope.

You instead passed the function as parameter, so the function body gets appended to the url.

```
var Page = {
    viewPage: {
        init: function() {
            lib.loadGoogleMapScript('Page.viewPage.initialize_map');
        },
        initialize_map: function() {
        }
    }
};

window.Page = Page;
```